# C: printing periods(.) with unistd write

Tags: c, hexdump, unistd.h

Among other things, my program is supposed to store any character with value less than 32 and greater than 126 as a period(.). It is then supposed to print out this period.

For example, if a newline character is passed to my printing function, it should store it as a period, and print out a period in its place.

(I am not allowed to use printf, only the system call "write")

This is the portion of my code that takes a character array of length 8 called asci and codes its characters to what needs to be printed:

```
unsigned char asci3[8];

    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {

        if ((asci[k] >= 32) || (asci[k] <= 126)) {
            asci3[k] = asci[k];                         
        }           

        else if ((asci[k] < 32) || (asci[k] > 126)) {
            asci3[k] = '.';                         
        }       

    }
```

This is how I print asci3:

```
if (write(1, asci3, 8) > 8) {
    return -1;                  
}
```

No periods are being printed. For example, for a newline character, a literal newline is being printed, instead of a period.

Comment: newline is 10, and `10 >= 32 || 10 <= 126` is true so it doesn't get replaced by a period. Can you see why `10 >= 32 || 10 <= 126` is true?

Comment: @immibis good catch!

Answer (score 0):

A silly mistake!

There was a logic error, instead of:

```
if ((asci[k] >= 32) || (asci[k] <= 126)) {
        asci3[k] = asci[k];                         
}           

else if ((asci[k] < 32) || (asci[k] > 126)) {
        asci3[k] = '.';                         
}
```

it should be:

```
if ((asci[k] >= 32) && (asci[k] <= 126)) {
        asci3[k] = asci[k];                         
}           

else if ((asci[k] < 32) || (asci[k] > 126)) {
        asci3[k] = '.';                         
}
```

The first `||` needed to be replaced with an `&&`.